# How does attribute class_name effect my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my web dev class we were given the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shouts
  has_many :followed_user_relationships, class_name: "FollowingRelationship"
  has_many :followed_users, through: :followed_user_relationships

  def follow(other_user)
    followed_users << other_user
  end
end
```

I understand everything except what class_name does. Does it add information to the model relationship somehow or does it just make this relationship an alias of that class name? [I checked out the documentations](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/class_name/class) and it seemed pretty worthless for someone new to rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails needs to know which class to instantiate for an association. It does this by guessing based on the association name, but it can only do this when your class and association are  named predictably. Specifically, it uses `String#classify` to turn an association name into a class name. `classify` converts from underscore case to camel case, and singularizes the word:

```
"some_kind_of_records".classify => "SomeKindOfRecord"
```

In your particular case, your association name and class name aren't related this way.
`:followed_user_relationships` would cause Rails to look for a class called `FollowedUserRelationship`, which isn't the right class, `FollowingRelationship`.

Because you've deviated slightly from this convention, you have to explicitly tell Rails the name of the class involved. That's all `class_name` does. It tells Rails the name of the class to use, when Rails isn't able to guess correctly.

Consider a simpler example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end
```

How could Rails know that a `Post` is associated with a `User`, if all we had written was `belongs_to :author`?

Comment: Sorry for the basic question but what do you mean by, "Rails needs to know which class to instantiate for an association.", I thought the only classes related to associations were either models or controllers, are you referring to one of them, or is it something completely different? Are you referring to the database itself?

Comment: Controllers have nothing to do with associations. I'm talking exclusively about models. Your models have associations, and associations are defined by the methods `has_many`, `belongs_to`, etc. You give those methods an association name, like `has_many :users`. Rails uses the association name to figure out which two models you're trying to associate, but it can only do so when the name and the model are similar. If they're not, you need to tell it which model to use.